# Filtering depending on specific conditions in rows

Tags: r, tidyverse, filtering

I hope someone can help me with this problem. I have a dataframe similar to the following one, but much larger:

```
participant <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2)
task <- c("a", "a", "b", "b", "a","a", "b", "b")
name <- c("Maria", "Laura", "Laura", "Maria", "Laura", "Maria", "Maria", "Laura")
correct <- c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)
df <- data.frame(participant, task, name, correct)
```

What I would like to do is to get a new dataframe containing only data for task "a", but filtering out the names that are correct = 0 in task b. Basically I would like to obtain this dataframe:

```
participant <- c(1,2)
task <- c("a", "a")
name <- c("Maria", "Laura")
correct <- c(1,0)
df2 <- data.frame(participant, task, name, correct)
```

Any idea about how to do this in tidyverse?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I have edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is your desired approach, but the output differs, since the logic is not explicit enough.

The idea is to first `filter(task == "a")` and then  `semi_join()` (which is a filtering join) the result on "participant" and "name" of `filter(df, correct == 0, task == "b")`.

At least that is how I understand the desired operation. Note that akruns answer yields the desired outcome, but doesn't use `task == "b"` as condition (it only uses `correct == 0`).

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(task == "a") %>% 
  semi_join(.,
            filter(df,
                   correct == 0,
                   task == "b"),
            by = c("participant", "name")
            )
#>   participant task  name correct
#> 1           1    a Laura       1
#> 2           2    a Maria       0
```

Alternatively we could just use `"name"` in the `semi_join()`, but this yields too many names:

```r
df %>% 
  filter(task == "a") %>% 
  semi_join(.,
            filter(df,
                   correct == 0,
                   task == "b"),
            by = "name"
  )
#>   participant task  name correct
#> 1           1    a Maria       1
#> 2           1    a Laura       1
#> 3           2    a Laura       1
#> 4           2    a Maria       0
```

The OP's data

```r
participant <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2)
task <- c("a", "a", "b", "b", "a","a", "b", "b")
name <- c("Maria", "Laura", "Laura", "Maria", "Laura", "Maria", "Maria", "Laura")
correct <- c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)
df <- data.frame(participant, task, name, correct)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

We may do a group by `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(participant) %>%
    filter(!name %in% name[correct == 0], task == 'a') %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  participant task  name  correct
        <dbl> <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
1           1 a     Maria       1
2           2 a     Laura       1
```

-OP's expected output

```
> df2
  participant task  name correct
1           1    a Maria       1
2           2    a Laura       1
```

---

In the `devel` version of `dplyr`, we may also use `.by` in `filter`

```
df %>% 
   filter(! name %in% name[correct == 0], task == 'a', .by = 'participant')
```

-output

```
   participant task  name correct
1           1    a Maria       1
2           2    a Laura       1
```

Comment: thanks akruns. I actually tried something very similar to what you did, but it did not work, as it does not use task == "b" as TimTeaFan mentioned

Comment: @ajestudillo hello Sir, would you be kind enough to modify your expected output?  At present, it is matching with the output I showed.  Sorry, I would have guessed the expected output if you didn't provide it in your post

Comment: my apologies @akrun. It is now modified.